# Convert a RGB image to grayscale img

Tags: python, arrays, rgb, reshape, grayscale

```py
arr = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    image = x1[i].reshape(150, 150, 3)
    grayscale = image[0:150, 0:150, 1]
    grayscale = grayscale.reshape(22500)
    arr = np.append(arr, np.array(grayscale), axis=0)

print(arr.shape)  # (742500,)
```

I am working on a school project, and I have created more data with augmentation in RGB format. I would like to convert this to grayscale after augmentation because it will require fewer computations. However, for some reason, I am having problems with appending the reshaped version into a new array. It is append everything into one row and not to a separate rows, I want to have (33,22500) not (742500), can anyone help plz

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways;
way1:

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    image = x1[i].reshape(150,150,3)
    grayscale = image[:150,:150,1]
    grayscale = grayscale.reshape(22500)
    arr.append(grayscale)

arr = np.array(arr)
```